# My reaction roles command won't work in Discord.js v12

Tags: discord, discord.js

Ok so... I've been attempting to make a reaction roles command but it won't work. The role isn't given to the user. It gives me this error "ReferenceError: reaction is not defined"

Code:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL","REACTION"]});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if(message.content === '>reactions'){
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Reaction Roles')
        .setDescription('React to obtain your roles!')
        .setColor('#242323')
        let MessageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed)
        MessageEmbed.react('‍')
    }
    if(reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if(reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();

    if(user.client) return;
    if(!reaction.message.guild) return;

    if(reaction.message.channel.id === "759064796611215442") {
        if(reaction.emoji.name === '‍'){
            await reaction.message.guild.member.cache.get(user.id).roles.add('760838222057046046')
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I mean... `reaction` isn't defined? What do you want?

Comment: How do I fix my code? I'm also a beginner . Sorry

Comment: Well what do you want `reaction` to be?

Comment: I want it so that it would give the "Son" role after the user reacts with "‍". My reaction roles channel ID is "759064796611215442" and my Son role ID is "760838222057046046"

Comment: You can use a [reaction collector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions)

Comment: That's very confusing to me

Comment: [Official Discord.js Guide - Reaction Collectors](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-reaction-collector)